# Parse repeated occurance of +d in a line

Tags: python, regex

This is the line to parse: `001000000 +3 12091992 +2 0200 +3`

I have used like:

```
Z = re.compile('(?P<stop_id>\d{9}) (?P<time_displacement>([-|+]\d{0,4})*)', flags=re.UNICODE)

m = Z.search('001000000 +3 12091992 +2 0200 +3')
if m:
    yield {
           'stop_id': m.group('stop_id')
          }
    if m.group('time_displacement'):
        _suffix=_suffix + 1
        yield {
               'time_displacement' + str(_suffix): m.group('time_displacement')
              }
```

This is the result:

```
[{'stop_id': '001000000'}, {'time_displacement': '+3'}]
```

But I need:

```
[{'stop_id': '001000000'}, {'time_displacement1': '+3'},{'time_displacement2': '+2'},{'time_displacement1': '+3'}]
```

Comment: This code cannot produce this output (the `'time_displacement'` key in particular)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `yield`? Presumably the code you posted is part of a generator function. Please consider posting code fragments that are actually runnable...

And why do you want a list of single element `dict`s rather than putting everything into a single `dict`???

From your code & data sample I'm not totally sure of exactly what should & shouldn't match, but hopefully this does what you need... or is fairly close. :)

Anyway, you could do it like this:

```
import re

fields = ('stop_id', 'time_displacement')
pat = re.compile(r'(\d{9})|([-|+]\d{0,4})')

data = '001000000 +3 12091992 +2 0200 +3'
found = pat.findall(data)
#print found

result = []
suffix = 1
for p1, p2 in found:
    if p2 == '':
        result.append({fields[0]: p1})
    elif p1 == '':
        result.append({fields[1]+str(suffix): p2})
        suffix += 1

print result
```

**Output**

```
[{'stop_id': '001000000'}, {'time_displacement1': '+3'}, {'time_displacement2': '+2'}, {'time_displacement3': '+3'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(?P<stop_id>\d{9})|(?P<time_displacement>(?:[-|+]\d{0,4}))
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/1